# Django 1.4 - Keeping track of multiple queries and pagination

Tags: django

I have a site that basically displays a huge table of people that I want to be able to filter, sort and page through. I want to do this in multiple views that have different preexisting constraints on which people are displayed in the table. My problem is that, if I filter by state for example, sort by name, and then try to go to the next page, it resets. For example, if I filter once I get my/url/2013/?sort=n&state=MN&page=1; then if I go to page 2, I just get my/url/2013/?page=2. It doesn't remember what I've already asked it.

```
def all(request, year=default_year):

#sorting (sort_options was defined prior to this view)
if 'sort' in request.GET:
    sort = request.GET.get('sort')
    order = sort_options[sort]
else:
    order = '-score'


players = Player.objects.filter(year=year).order_by(order)
url_query = ''

#filtering
if 'position' in request.GET:
    filterData = _filter(request,players)
    players = filterData['players']
    url_query += filterData['url_query']

# pagination
paginator = Paginator(players,25)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    players = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    players = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    players = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

data = {'players':players,'url_query':url_query}

return render_to_response('all.html', data, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In my template I reference url_query like so:

```
<th class="name"><a href="?sort=n&{{url_query}}&page={{players.number}}">Name</a></th>
```

and like so:

```
<a href="?{{url_query}}&page={{ players.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
```

This is pretty obviously wrong to me but I don't know how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your template you can pass to the context (in your case `data`) object `sort` parameter and then in the template you can use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) to show which view to invoke.

Comment: So have data = {'players':players,'url_query':url_query,'sort':sort}? Sorry, I don't totally understand what you mean. Could you include some code?

Comment: Yes, when you render your template you pass the sort object.